# Feature selection when data is less, sparse and imbalanced

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, analytics, feature-selection

Is there any way to select the features when i am having less, sparse and imbalanced data.

Around 90% of samples are ordinal and 10% are numerical.

Number of features: 200
Number of samples: around 1000

Comment: There is no fixed approach. You should try out different algorithms with cross validation and see what works best for you. If no single algorithm works, try ensemble

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to do feature selection for sparse data. The possible approaches are:

- chi-2 based feature selection
- RandomForestClassifier/RandomForestRegressor
- xgboost

Try doing feature selection in the original dataset and in the balanced dataset using oversampling techniques (such as SMOTE) or undersampling. SMOTE stands for Synthetic Minority Over-sampling. There is a dedicated package for balancing imbalanced datasets in Python. You may use this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imbalanced-learn.

Some kind of domain knowledge is preferred in feature selection as suggested in [this](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/guyon03a/guyon03a.pdf) highly cited paper on feature selection. Compare the feature importance on balanced and the original data to do the final selection of features.

*References:*

http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/07/21/approaching-almost-any-machine-learning-problem-abhishek-thakur/

http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html#sklearn.feature_selection.chi2

http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/feature_selection.html

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume16/chawla02a-html/node6.html

Comment: AFAIK, these techniques require sufficient amount of data. Is it the case? What do you think? I have used SMOTE for oversampling by using imbalanced-learn.

Comment: @Gagan These methods usually work well when the sample size is around 1000. More info http://www.biostathandbook.com/small.html

Comment: Its a recommendation problem so I was using KNN at the end. For that i needed feature selection first. The target variable is nominal. Now would you advise me to use RF, chi2 feature selection, etc?

Comment: @Gagan So you mean you don't have the label information. In that case, use may use the Variance Threshold (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#removing-features-with-low-variance) technique which does not require class/group information.

Comment: Thanks. And if i have the labels then which could RF be choosen for the feature selection with KNN used for modelling?